# Missing template (jbuilder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

Rails trying to find users folder with jbuilder files, which exist, but can't

[Application](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/poller)

```
Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/bjorn/Documents/poller/app/views"
  * "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.37/app/views"
  * "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.0.3/app/views"
```

[full error stack](http://pastebin.com/ftxYJzrf)

```
# controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :users, only: [ :index, :show ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and I don't get this exception at `/api/users`.

However you need to rename your layout file `application.slim` to `application.html.slim`. Otherwise jbuilder will render the layout too.